# WAP: Any good simulators still available?

Tags: simulator, wap, wml

I'm busy playing around with WML and was just wondering if there are any simulators still available? I have looked around quite a bit and have encountered a lot of dead links.

Answer (score 0):

> RESOLVED: M3Gate appears to work nicely